# Having problem with some packages unloaded

Tags: r

I searched through Stackoverflow, but could not find a straightforward answer for my question. So, I want to do ordered logit modeling via using rms package. So, I installed this package, and after calling it through Library, I get the following:

```
> library("rms")
Loading required package: Hmisc
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: Formula
Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: ‘Hmisc’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    format.pval, units

Loading required package: SparseM

Attaching package: ‘SparseM’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    backsolve
```

So far, it is not a problem. Therefore, I installed all the mentioned packages. Then, again after running Library(rms), I faced the following:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rms’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘zoo’
```

I am confused. I uninstalled RStudio, and re-installed it, but, no change. Also, I have the same issue with other packages. For example, I tried to call package of MASS, same issue.

```
    > library("MASS", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library") 
Error in value[[3L]](cond) :    
  Package ‘MASS’ version 7.3.51.1 cannot be unloaded:  
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘MASS’ is imported by ‘rockchalk’, ‘lme4’ so cannot be unloaded
```

Comment: Based on the error, please install `zoo` first `install.packages('zoo')`  Also, it could be that all the dependencies were not instaalled earlier.  So, a better option would be to remove the package, reinstall with `dependencies = TRUE`  in the `install.packages`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did what you said, and it worked.